# Does spring '<props>' support '#{ myprops['abc'] }' expression?

Tags: java, spring

I define a properties holder:

```
<util:properties id="myProps" location="file:my.properties" />
```

Then I can use `#{}` expression in `<property>`:

```
<bean id="mybean" class="test.MyBean">
    <property name="hello" value="#{ myProps['hello'] }"/>
</bean>
```

But when I define this bean:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.domain"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">#{ myProps['db.timeout']}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My Intellij-IDEA mark `#{ myProps['db.timeout']}` in red, and has tip:

```
Can't resolve symbol: #{ myProps['db.timeout']}
```

Does '' support `#{}` expressions? And how to fix this problem?

---

Thank for subhashis's answer, but I forgot to mention I can't use `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in the project due to some design limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it supports the expression but instead of using # use $ see the below sample

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">


    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
           <value>database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
     </bean>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I can't use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in the project(due to some design limitations)